# Celery and lost messages

Tags: redis, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

The following snippet of code initiates the tasks launch in my Celery installation:

**tasks.py**:

```
@app.task(ignore_result=False)
def asyncTransactionTask(txid):
    Here I do something with txid and do not schedule additional tasks

@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def asyncCheckNotifications(*args):

    try:
        payments = # get an array of values
        payments_tasks = []
        for payment in payments:
            payments_tasks.append(asyncTransactionTask.s(payment))

        chain(group(payments_tasks) | asyncCheckNotifications.subtask()).apply_async(countdown=60)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(str(e))
        asyncCheckNotifications.apply_async(countdown=10)
        raise e

asyncCheckNotifications.delay()
```

I expected to see the `asyncCheckNotifications` method running roughly every minute, whereas I receive them every **two** minutes.

What is more, if I check the scheduled tasks (`celery -A myapp inspect scheduled`), I see the method execution appropriately scheduled, but when I reach the timeout, it is simply replaced by another schedule for the next minute and nothing is run.

I am using Celery 3.1.8.
The message broker is RabbitMQ 3.2.4.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I have solved my problem by replacing the following:

```
chain(group(payments_tasks) | asyncCheckNotifications.subtask()).apply_async(countdown=60)
```

with the following:

```
    chain(group(payments_tasks) | asyncCheckNotifications.subtask(countdown=60)).delay()
```